# Can I change the href value of a link using javascript RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

You may have see various sites where URLs are encoded by an advertisement redirection service. I want to write a personal javascript snippet to remove this spam.

Mostly, the HTML will look like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://ads.example.com/246619/http://www.example.net/path/I/want">SteamTable App</a>
```

The problem is that the URL path `http://ads.example.com/`**246619**`/` is different for each link.

My attempt:

```
$(function() {
    var x = $('div.content.clearfix a').get();
    //alert(x.length);
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var Href = $(x[i]).attr('href');

        Href = Href.replace("http://ads.example.com/.*?/", "");
        alert(Href);  //success or not
        $(x[i]).attr('href', Href);
    }
});
```

[Demo on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/defencedog/3kAtv/4/).

I don't know why this isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the quotes around your regex and use regex delimiters

```
Href = Href.replace(/http:\/\/url.sh\/.*?\//, "");
```

Comment: what is the difference b/w my method & this one:`Href=Href.replace( /http\:\/\/url.sh\/[^\/]+\//i, "") ;`

Comment: The `[^\/]+` is a substitution for the lazy matching of all characters `.*?`. Its matching any character, but the slash, so the result should be the same. This regex is ending with the `i` modifier its making the regex matching case independend, i.e. "a" will also match "A", but since there are not letters in the regex its useless here.